# How to write code for an auto clicker that clicks on a particular link in a webpage in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So, I have very little coding background and hence have absolutely no idea how to even approach this.

I'm trying to browse [Fortune Tech](http://fortune.com/tech/) to read news from most of 2016 and there's a link when you scroll to the end which you need to click in order to view more headlines. It says " See more Tech Headlines". I wanted to somehow automate this process, like I'd scroll down and it'll automatically load the next set of headlines without me having to click there. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can help get you started. You will want to download the extension [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) so you can inject code into a webpage automatically. This is the code you want to have in a custom script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name      Fortune Tech Auto Click
// @author    Some Random Guy On The Internet
// @include   http://fortune.com/tech/
// @include   http://someothersite.com/*
// @require   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
          if (document.location.href.search('fortune.com/tech') !== -1) {  // This will run only on the fortune tech site
              $("#section-see-more").trigger("click"); 
          }else if (document.location.href.search('someothersite.com/*') !== -1) { // this will run on the someother.com/* site
              // Selector of the button.
              $("#other-button-id").trigger("click");
          }
       }
    });

})();
```

You will probably need to play around with it a little to get it working.

Edited to fit below comment better.

Comment: Wow - I'm not the OP, but I tested this out and it worked flawlessly. Very useful answer, you taught me how easy it is to write a full Tampermonkey script!

Comment: @Prathamesh - glad to help!

Comment: @Loaf- I was tinkering around with your script to automate some other pages I visit. Keeping the condition same, that is scrolling to the end of the page, how do I modify the URL. Like what would be the syntax to go to "example.com/page/2" from "example.com/page/1" when the "if" is satisfied

Comment: @Prathamesh - I edited my origional answer to suit your comment. If you want to include more sites for the script to run, just add more `// @include` lines to the top. I also added another `if / elseif` to the script to handle different pages.

You will need to get the element ID of button you want to click or the selector. To get that you will need to inspect the page and look at the the button to see if there is a `id="button-id-name"` in the tag.

Comment: @Loaf- I understood the button clicking part completely. What is the purpose of (document.location.href.search('fortune.com/tech') !== -1), btw?

Apart from that, I wanted to know, how on satisfying the if condition, I get the code to go to a different page entirely. As in, when I scroll to the end of "example.com/page/1", the if condition gets triggered and I go to "example.com/page/2", like the number at the end of the URL gets added by one.

Comment: @Prathamesh - Oh okay, I misunderstood. The `document.location.href.search` part will only run the block of code on the page that matches what is in the parameters. That way it doesn't try to click on an element that doesn't exists. If you try to do more complicated things it may stop your script entirely because it could be trying to do it on any page you have in the `// @include` Give me a moment and I'll test the page incrementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132240/discussion-between-loaf-and-prathamesh).

Answer (score 0):

**Using JQuery:**

```
$('#section-see-more').click();
$('html, body').animate({ 
   scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()}, 
   1400, 
   "easeOutQuint"
);
```

The website you mentioned does not currently have jQuery on it, so you would have to load it into the page manually.

This is a tedious process unless you make a browser extension for this website and use the code to click the link that loads more information onto the screen.